# How do I set OWIN keys like host.AppMode when running under IIS (Host.SystemWeb)?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2, owin

In the OWIN pipeline of an application I'm refactoring, I've found the following code snippet:

```
private bool IsDevelopment(IAppBuilder app)
{
    const string appModeKey = "host.AppMode";
    if (app.Properties.ContainsKey(appModeKey))
    {
        var appMode = app.Properties[appModeKey] as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appMode))
        {
            return appMode.Equals("development", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The result of this method is then used to make decisions on e.g. what components to include in the pipeline:

```
if (IsDevelopment(app))
{
    app.Use<DevelopmentAuthMiddleware>();
}
else
{
    app.Use<ProductionAuthMiddleware>();
}
```

Now, in a new test environment I'm setting up, I'd like to - for now, but not forever - use the development config.

Is there a way I can accomplish that without changing the decision-making code? In other words, how do I set `app.Properties["host.AppMode"]` to `"development"` from outside of the application code?

(AppSettings or similar in Web.config would work, if I could figure out how; I can change those at deploy-time, since they vary by environment anyway.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/9f6e09af6bf203744feb5347121fe25f6eec06d8/src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/OwinAppContext.cs#L70) for *Host.SystemWeb* there is a portion of code that directly sets the `host.AppMode` to *developer* based on whether the `system.web/compilation` in *web.config* is set to debug.

```
CompilationSection compilationSection = (CompilationSection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(@"system.web/compilation");
bool isDebugEnabled = compilationSection.Debug;
if (isDebugEnabled)
{
    builder.Properties[Constants.HostAppModeKey] = Constants.AppModeDevelopment;
}
```

Through out the source there is no other direct access to that property where it is being set.

So my suggestion would be to update the *web.config* file

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
```

which should allow the setting of `app.Properties["host.AppMode"]` to *"development"* from outside of the application code.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using "old" Asp.Net, then the easiest way would be to use [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) for reading keys from `<appSettings>` section of web.config, ie:

```
private bool IsDevelopment(IAppBuilder app) {
    return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["isDevelopment"] == "true";
}
```

And in web.config:

```
<appSettings>  
  <add key="isDevelopment" value="true" />       
</appSettings>
```

Asp.Net Core uses [Env variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1) by default to achieve similar thing.

Comment: This is "old" ASP.NET, not .NET Core, but it's still OWIN. I know how ASP.NET Core does it, and I know there are lots of other ways to achieve similar results, but that does not help me switching this behavior _without changing application code_. (It also doesn't teach me anything about the `IAppBuilder.Properties` dictionary.)